# Laravel 5 MethodNotAllowedHttpException after validation fails (going back to POST)

Tags: laravel, validation, methods, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I shall try to be as explicit as possible…I am quite new in Laravel…

Process:

1)  I have a view with form where a customer should enter a promo; I have a PromoRequest to validate this promo code ;

2)  I have a view with a form where, if the promo code passed the rules, the customer should fill in his data; I have a CustRequest to validate his date (p.e. ‘email’ => ‘required’ etc)

3)  And finally I have a confirmation view to show the customer data with a validation button; if find, I store the data in a DB, and send an email

Issue:

1)  The first step works fine

2)  In the second view, if my validation rule fails (p.e. no email), I got a **MethodNotAllowedHttpException**
I understand that if the inscription validation fails (no email), it goes back to my inscription form which is a POST method…and that brings the problem…

How can I sort that out???

Thanks

Comment: This usually is caused by making a POST request to a GET route or vice versa. Can you explain a little bit longer? are you displaying a form in POST route?

Answer (score -1):

This is probably way too late, however I came across this question as I had the same issue and thought I would describe what I had done in error...

For me, I was building a site where users would submit photos. When the user clicked on the "add photo" it took them to a page where they had to check a box to accept a legal disclaimer. This form with the checkbox was a POST request. After they accepted it they would get re-directed to the submission page... WHICH WAS ALSO A FORM WITH A POST REQUEST. This was my issue: back to back POST request pages. If the user entered invalid data on the submission form, or didn't enter data in a field at all Laravel tries to essentially hit the "back button" in your browser and keep the form filled what the data the user did enter. The problem is that the "back" button (or the way the user came to this page) was from a POST request, so it couldn't do it. It gave me the error described above. Once I switched the legal acceptance page to a GET request form and updated the route to match everything started working fine. It was a foolish error on my part, I just hope to mitigate this frustration for others as they are learning to develop in Laravel.